# Java - Calculator GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, calculator

Yes, I am aware that this question has been asked before; however, our methods of conducting the functions are different and for this reason I believe that this should not be marked as a duplicate.

I am trying to make a Calculator GUI Function, but currently all I can do is have the user click on a number, and then have that number printed out to the screen.

When I click the divide function (this is the only one I have set up currently), "1" is printed out to the screen. Obviously this is not an error, since I am getting the user's input (the number clicked) twice without change. That number divided by itself (which is essentially what I am doing right now) is 1.

This is my current code:

```
package my.calculator;

public class CalculatorUI extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
    public CalculatorUI() 
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        Output = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        One = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Two = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Three = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Four = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Five = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Six = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Seven = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Eight = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Nine = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Zero = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Divide = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Multiply = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Subtract = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Add = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Clear = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Calc = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Output.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                OutputPropertyChange(evt);
            }
        });

        One.setText("1");
        One.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                OneActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Two.setText("2");
        Two.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                TwoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Three.setText("3");
        Three.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ThreeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Four.setText("4");
        Four.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                FourActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Five.setText("5");
        Five.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                FiveActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Six.setText("6");
        Six.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SixActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Seven.setText("7");
        Seven.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SevenActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Eight.setText("8");
        Eight.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                EightActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Nine.setText("9");
        Nine.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                NineActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Zero.setText("0");
        Zero.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ZeroActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Divide.setText("/");
        Divide.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                DivideActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Multiply.setText("X");

        Subtract.setText("-");

        Add.setText("+");

        Clear.setText("C");
        Clear.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ClearActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Calc.setText("=");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(Output)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(One)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(Two)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(Three, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(Four)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(Five)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(Six, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(Seven)
                            .addComponent(Clear))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(Eight)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(Nine, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(Zero)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(Calc)))))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(Add)
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addComponent(Subtract, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(4, 4, 4)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(Multiply, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(Divide, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(Output, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(Three, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(One)
                                    .addComponent(Two))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(Four)
                                    .addComponent(Five)
                                    .addComponent(Six)
                                    .addComponent(Multiply))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(Seven)
                                    .addComponent(Eight)
                                    .addComponent(Nine)
                                    .addComponent(Subtract))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(Zero)
                                    .addComponent(Add)
                                    .addComponent(Calc)
                                    .addComponent(Clear)))
                            .addComponent(Divide, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void OneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        Output.setText(String.valueOf(1));
    }                                   

    private void ClearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        Output.setText(String.valueOf(""));        
    }                                     

    private void TwoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        Output.setText(String.valueOf(2));
    }                                   

    private void ThreeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        Output.setText(String.valueOf(3));        
    }                                     

    private void FourActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        Output.setText(String.valueOf(4));        
    }                                    

    private void FiveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        Output.setText(String.valueOf(5));        
    }                                    

    private void SixActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        Output.setText(String.valueOf(6));        
    }                                   

    private void SevenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        Output.setText(String.valueOf(7));        
    }                                     

    private void EightActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        Output.setText(String.valueOf(8));        
    }                                     

    private void NineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        Output.setText(String.valueOf(9));        
    }                                    

    private void ZeroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        Output.setText(String.valueOf(0));        
    }                                    

    private void DivideActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(Output.getText());
        int number = Integer.parseInt(Output.getText());
        int calculate = num1  / number;
        Output.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
    }                                      

    private void OutputPropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {                                      
        Output.setEditable(false);        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalculatorUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalculatorUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalculatorUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalculatorUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CalculatorUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton Add;
    private javax.swing.JButton Calc;
    private javax.swing.JButton Clear;
    private javax.swing.JButton Divide;
    private javax.swing.JButton Eight;
    private javax.swing.JButton Five;
    private javax.swing.JButton Four;
    private javax.swing.JButton Multiply;
    private javax.swing.JButton Nine;
    private javax.swing.JButton One;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Output;
    private javax.swing.JButton Seven;
    private javax.swing.JButton Six;
    private javax.swing.JButton Subtract;
    private javax.swing.JButton Three;
    private javax.swing.JButton Two;
    private javax.swing.JButton Zero;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I would also like to include a decimal function (so that you can have doubles, etc), but am lost as to how to do so. Any and all help regarding both questions is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Easy recommendations: (1) Learn about the import statement, (2) Learn about looping and arrays.  Too much ugly, repetitive code here to be considered good.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's tempting but I consider a calculater (even if it's just for basic arithmetic)  not quite as trivial as it might look for a beginner. How would you e.g. solve an expression like 3+3*2? What you need for starters is a Parser/Tokenizer an intermediate format like the polish notation and an algorithm to get the order right e.g. the shanting yard algorithm.